# d3.js not able to parse my string into date despite seemingly correct format? (v4)

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, d3.js

I am using d3js v4. The following is what my date string looks like:

```
var ds = "2019-02-18 22:38:18.327717";
```

I have set up my parser like so:

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L");
```

I then try and pass this string into parseDate like so:

```
var parsed_date_value = parseDate(ds);
```

But parsed_date_value is null after this. I figure there is some issue with the seconds part of my time format but it looks correct and I am not sure. Seems to me this date string matches this format im passing to d3.timeParse()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your format string, you need to use microseconds (`%f`) instead of milliseconds (`%L`).

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f");
```

The complete reference is here: https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locale_format

Answer (score 1):

as per the documentation [https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format]:

```
%L - milliseconds as a decimal number [000, 999].
%f - microseconds as a decimal number [000000, 999999].
```

Here my L clearly was not on the range [000,999] like required by the docs. Instead it looks to be on the range [000000, 999999] so using the following fixed it:

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f");
```